# Is it possible to to leave Uri empty? because when i click next without image in it, its became force closed -Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Please help me, so i'm trying to update some data but i don't wanna insert an image when i click save it force closed. and when i insert an image its work. i don't understand what's wrong. the logcat always pointing to filePath which is Uri, it is possible to not insert image ?

is there anyone can figure it out what's wrong and help me?

Thank you in advance

**Here's my Code**

```
class DetailPerkembanganTanaman : AppCompatActivity() {

private var perkembanganList = ArrayList<Perkembangan_Tanaman>()
val REQUEST_CODE = 100

private lateinit var mFirebaseInstance: FirebaseDatabase
private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var preferences: Preferences

lateinit var storage: FirebaseStorage
lateinit var storageReference: StorageReference
lateinit var filePath: Uri
var getUrl = ""

private var nmTanaman = ""
private var status = " "
private var estimasi_panen = " "
private var deskripsi_pertumbuhan = ""
private var url_photo = ""
private var idPerkembangan = ""
private var tglMulai = ""
private var tglUpdate = ""
private var idJasa = ""
private var getUsername = ""
private var tambahDurasi = ""

private var getDurasiJasa = ""
private var diffDate = ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_perkembangan_tanaman)

    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    preferences = Preferences(this)
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    storageReference = storage.reference

    idPerkembangan = intent.getStringExtra("id_perkembangan").toString()
    getUsername = intent.getStringExtra("username").toString()

    btn_tambah_photo_detail_perkembangan.setOnClickListener {
        pickImageFromGallery()
    }

    btn_back_detail_perkembangan.setOnClickListener { finish() }

    btn_simpan_detail_perkembangan.setOnClickListener {  updateData() }

    btn_batal_detail_perkembangan.setOnClickListener { finish() }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

        filePath = data!!.data!!

        btn_tambah_photo_detail_perkembangan.setImageURI(data.data) // handle chosen image
        btn_tambah_photo_detail_perkembangan.layoutParams.height =
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        btn_tambah_photo_detail_perkembangan.layoutParams.width =
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        btn_tambah_photo_detail_perkembangan.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
        btn_tambah_photo_detail_perkembangan.setBackgroundResource(0)
    }else{
        Log.d("Myactivity", "onActivityResult:disini coy ")
    }
}


private fun pickImageFromGallery() {

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    intent.type = "image/*"

    val mimeTypes =
        arrayOf("image/jpeg", "image/png")
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)

}

private fun updateData() {

    val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
    progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...")
    progressDialog.show()

    getUrl = ""
    val ref = storageReference.child("perkembangan/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    val uploadTask = ref.putFile(filePath)

    uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
            task.exception?.let {
                throw it
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "gagal cuy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        ref.downloadUrl
    }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            progressDialog.dismiss()
            val downloadUrl = task.result
            getUrl = downloadUrl.toString()

            Toast.makeText(this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            finish()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "dapat url gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
}
```

**and Here's the Error**

```
 Process: com.example.kebonadmin, PID: 7490
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property filePath has not been initialized
    at com.example.kebonadmin.DetailPerkembanganTanaman.updateData(DetailPerkembanganTanaman.kt:240)
    at com.example.kebonadmin.DetailPerkembanganTanaman.access$updateData(DetailPerkembanganTanaman.kt:31)
    at com.example.kebonadmin.DetailPerkembanganTanaman$onCreate$3.onClick(DetailPerkembanganTanaman.kt:82)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6913)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6890)
    at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:792)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27158)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:209)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7021)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:486)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:872)
```

Comment: Please have a look at this section of the Kotlin documentation to find out why the error you are encountering occurs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables. Especially the subsection "Checking whether a lateinit var is initialized (since 1.2)" should be very interesting for you.
If you can't find a solution on your own after reading this, please update the question with some details about what you tried to solve it so far or at least why you think the error happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because you have not initialized the variable `filePath` (which is marked as lateinit) and then you are assigning the uri like this ---> `filePath = data!!.data!!`

When you specify a variable as **lateinit** you are promising the compiler that you will initialize the variable before using it. (here you are assigning the uri)

What you can do is initialize a makeshift string variable `uriHolder` and reassign the value of `uriHolder` with the uri that you get in the `onActivityResult` method (as a string) like this ---> `uriHolder = filepath.toString()` and then in updateData method use the `uriHolder` variable to get the uri from the `uriHolder` string like this --->

`val filePath: Uri = Uri.parse(uriHolder)`

(and finally use it) like this --->

`val uploadTask = ref.putFile(filePath)`

**ACTUAL SOLUTION CODE:**

```
class DetailPerkembanganTanaman : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var perkembanganList = ArrayList<Perkembangan_Tanaman>()
    val REQUEST_CODE = 100

    private lateinit var mFirebaseInstance: FirebaseDatabase
    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var preferences: Preferences

    lateinit var storage: FirebaseStorage
    lateinit var storageReference: StorageReference
    var uriHolder = ""
    var getUrl = ""

    private var nmTanaman = ""
    private var status = " "
    private var estimasi_panen = " "
    private var deskripsi_pertumbuhan = ""
    private var url_photo = ""
    private var idPerkembangan = ""
    private var tglMulai = ""
    private var tglUpdate = ""
    private var idJasa = ""
    private var getUsername = ""
    private var tambahDurasi = ""

    private var getDurasiJasa = ""
    private var diffDate = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_perkembangan_tanaman)

        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        preferences = Preferences(this)
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        storageReference = storage.reference

        idPerkembangan = intent.getStringExtra("id_perkembangan").toString()
        getUsername = intent.getStringExtra("username").toString()

        btn_tambah_photo_detail_perkembangan.setOnClickListener {
            pickImageFromGallery()
        }

        btn_back_detail_perkembangan.setOnClickListener { finish() }

        btn_simpan_detail_perkembangan.setOnClickListener { updateData() }

        btn_batal_detail_perkembangan.setOnClickListener { finish() }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            var filePath: Uri
            filePath = data!!.data!!  
            uriHolder = filePath.toString()

            btn_tambah_photo_detail_perkembangan.setImageURI(data.data) // handle chosen image
            btn_tambah_photo_detail_perkembangan.layoutParams.height =
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            btn_tambah_photo_detail_perkembangan.layoutParams.width =
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            btn_tambah_photo_detail_perkembangan.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
            btn_tambah_photo_detail_perkembangan.setBackgroundResource(0)
        } else {
            Log.d("Myactivity", "onActivityResult:disini coy ")
        }
    }


    private fun pickImageFromGallery() {

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"

        val mimeTypes =
                arrayOf("image/jpeg", "image/png")
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)

    }

    private fun updateData() {

        val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...")
        progressDialog.show()

        getUrl = ""
        val ref = storageReference.child("perkembangan/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        val filePath: Uri = Uri.parse(uriHolder)
        val uploadTask = ref.putFile(filePath)

        uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                task.exception?.let {
                    throw it
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "gagal cuy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            ref.downloadUrl
        }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                progressDialog.dismiss()
                val downloadUrl = task.result
                getUrl = downloadUrl.toString()

                Toast.makeText(this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "dapat url gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but then in function updateData in val uploadTask can't be used